# Advise a Drupal Image gallery module with an option to put text nearby the image (for medical atlas)

Tags: media

Advise a Drupal Image gallery module with an option to put text nearby the image (for medical atlas). I could find a dozen of them, can`t choose before installing and setting them up. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Talking Drupal #083](http://www.talkingdrupal.com/083) is a great podcast about creating a Gallery, and includes a lot of recommended modules for it.

Just to mention a few of them (mentioned on the linked page):

> - [Gallery formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/galleryformatter).
> - [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow).
> - [Flexslider](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider).
> - [Node Gallery](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_gallery).
> - [Multiupload Filefield Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget).
> - [Multiupload Imagefield Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget).
> - [Field Focus](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_focus).
> - [pl upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload).

Comment: thank you, I need only one or two modules for medical atlas

Comment: thank you, now I can do what I had wished, could not find a faster/rapid in development technology, Joomla, MODX, and PHP YII and ASP MVC are competitors to Drupal, perhaps

Comment: for many years, I am gaining experience in several technologies, can`t find what is closer to my heart, that is not the topic for a forum